# Finding the Recurrence Relation from a python script

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, optimization, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find an upper bound for the following experiment:

1. For each participant, we perform 100 trials.
2. Before Each trial, I get to see the history of the current participant's choices and the rewards I gave for each trial.
3. There exist two different alternatives the participant must choose from.
4. If he chooses the alternative where I put the reward, he gets it. Otherwise, he doesn't see where I put the reward (If at all), meaning he only sees what he chose.
5. This goes on for all 100 Trials.

I have constraints upon me, and I must give a total of 25 rewards for each alternative ( So a total of 50 rewards over 100 trials).
I'm trying to bound the number of different "reward policies" that exist, now we must consider that each policy depends on the participant's previous choices.
I wrote a python program that will probably finish running at the heat death of the universe, and I was wondering if there might be a smarter combinatoric way to solve this issue probably making use of some recurrence relation.

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None, typed=False)
def num_policies(t, r1, r2, history):
    # Base case: no more trials
    if t == 0:
        return 1 if r1 == r2 == 0 else 0

    # Recursive case: calculate the number of policies depending on the participant's choice
    count = 0
    # If the participant chooses alternative 1
    if r1 > 0:
        count += num_policies(t - 1, r1 - 1, r2, history * 10 + 1)  # if you give a reward
    count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2, history * 10 + 1)  # if you don't give a reward

    # If the participant chooses alternative 2
    if r2 > 0:
        count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2 - 1, history * 10)  # if you give a reward
    count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2, history * 10)  # if you don't give a reward
    return count


print(timeit.timeit(lambda: num_policies(100, 25, 25, 0), number=1))
```

I would really appreciate ideas I can try out, or if I missed something I would be glad to know.

P.S I know this is code in MathExchange, this is not a mistake :)

## Solution

As pointed below the correct answer is:
14359430228704479165844944263707579471282278514667959615488

But looking this number of on OEIS gave me some interesting insight,
It appears in https://oeis.org/A051288, for n=100, and k=25. Described by the formula :
$$T(n, k) = binomial(n, 2\cdot k)\cdot2^{n-2\cdot k}\cdot binomial(2\cdot k, k)$$

If anyone has some intuition for why this is the case I'd love to hear.

Comment: You can use DP (dynamic programming) to make the code more efficient. Indeed without DP you get an exponential runtime. However I see you using @lru_cache  which is supposed to memoize results implicitly, in which case your current implementation is probably as efficient the dynamic programming solution.

Comment: Are you trying to get an exact number, or getting ballpark number, or some bounds?

Because obviously, the number of reward strategies will be astronimical.

Comment: In a recent similar problem, where you have to give a reward in every trial, the number of reward strategies is $2^{2^n-1}$ for $n$ trials.

Comment: I wrote a small program implementing the function you defined and used dynamic programming and the program finished in no time. Note that there are $O(t \cdot r_1 \cdot r_2)$ unique subproblems and each subproblem takes $O(1)$ time.

Comment: @Ingix Just a tight upper bound

Comment: @prcssngnr I would love to see it if possible

Comment: @Nadav I've added the pseudocode which is basically the same as the function you defined except that repeated computation is avoided using a 3D table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pseudocode of the function you defined, optimised using dynamic programming:

```
def num_policies(t, r1, r2, h, dp[][][]):
    
    if t == 0:
        return 1 if r1 == r2 == 0 else 0
    
    if dp[t][r1][r2] != -1:
        return dp[t][r1][r2];
        
    count = 0;
    
    if r1 > 0:
        count += num_policies(t - 1, r1 - 1, r2, h * 10 + 1, dp);
    
    count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2, h * 10 + 1, dp);
    
    if r2 > 0:
        count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2 - 1, h * 10, dp);
    
    count += num_policies(t - 1, r1, r2, h * 10, dp);
    
    dp[t][r1][r2] = count;
    
    return count;
```

We use a 3D array `dp[][][]` to store the results of each function call to avoid repeating computations. It is worth mentioning that the parameter $h$ is not used at all in the function definition and so has no impact on the results computed. Using this fact we have that the results depend only on $t,r_1,r_2$, which is why we use a 3D array for memoization.

With the function above we compute the value `count` to be $14359430228704479165844944263707579471282278514667959615488$ with input $t = 100$, $r_1 = 25$, $r_2 = 25$, $h = 0$.